# regex to replace char values for import file

Tags: mysql, regex, notepad++

I am trying to figure out a regex search and replace for a text file import.  There are hexadecimal values that need to be surrounded by the mysql char() function.

There is a comma and a space proceeding the value and a comma immediately after.

I am using a search and replace in my text editor, Notepad++

Examples of input:

```
, 0x31,
, 0x3137,
, 0x333731393831,
```

Desired result:

```
, char(0x31),
, char(0x3137),
, char(0x333731393831),
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `, (0x[0-9a-f]+),` with `, char(\1),`, with "Match case" unselected and "Regular expression" selected:

[image: Notepad++ find/replace example]

Answer (score 0):

`\b0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b` will match a hexidecimal number. ([Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/hex.html))

Just find that and replace it with `"char(" + match + ")";`

I don't know what the exact syntax for doing that in notepad++ is, but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: Doing just a regex search with that does not find anything in my document.

Comment: hmm, maybe try taking the \b 's out. I'm not sure what regex flavor notepad++ uses